# Android WebView does not use manually installed certificates

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, android-webview

I have a `WebView` in a Xamarin Forms application. It shows generated HTML which has references to resources on the intranet. These resources are TLS protected and a self signed certificate backs the secure communication.

The root-certificate is installed on the android device. Accessing it with google chrome works. However accessing it from WebView fails with an SSL error (3, untrusted).

For testing purposes, I changed the `WebViewClient` and overwrote `OnReceiveSslError`. There I check for my self signed certificate, allowing it manually (`handler.Proceed`). This works.
However this gives me new issues such as that the Navigating-event on the `Xamarin.Forms.WebView` does no more fire. Probably, I could also circumvent this problem, but everything seems a bit wrong.

To me it looks like as if the Android `WebView` does not use the same certificate store as that Google Chrome does. Is this correct and is there a fix to this behavior, hopefully without the necessity to create a custom renderer for the `WebView` control and introducing a whole bunch of potential new issues (such as the missing Navigating-event)?

**Update according to Jessie Zhang's request**
**Broken Navigating Event**
Attach in XAML a `Navigating` event. Assign a custom renderer for the `WebView` and in `OnElementChanged` assign a custom `WebviewClient` via `SetWebViewClient`. This step breaks the `Navigating` event, regardless whether the `OnReceiveSslError` is overriden or not (see code below).

**Certificate Error**
Use a WebView and assign it a custom built HTML via `HtmlWebViewSource` and embed some images which reference a https:// resource on a server with a self signed root-certificate (OpenSSL). Add the root certificate to the Android certificate store (via the User certificates applet). Although chrome and other clients accept now the https-resources, `WebView` does not. It seems as it does not consider the manually installed root certificate.
As an additional information: When overriding the `OnReceiveSslEvent` in WebViewClient, the certificate is available in the `SslError` parameter, however not accepted.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e) {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            Control.SetWebViewClient(
                new BreakingWebViewClient()
                );

        }
    }

class BreakingWebViewClient  : WebViewClient{
    // ... some code, but for breaking the Navigating-event, no code is necessary
}
```

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the detailed steps so that we can try to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @Jessie Zhang Hi Jessie, please see my updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue in a native Android project, installed certificates were respected by Chrome but not in embedded web views.

To fix the problem I needed to define a network security configuration.

In AndroidManifest.xml add the following attribute to the application node:
`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

Then create the file `xml/network_security_config.xml` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I believe the key line that fixes the problem is `<certificates src="user"/>` as user certificates are not included in the default configuration according to the docs.

Network security configuration documentation can be found here: https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config